# How can I use webpack just for bundle without webpack dev server?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, webpack

I have these parts of code folders [LINK](https://imgur.com/nIUQ6R7)

I work the server side with **node js /express** and from the client, side use **react** call route from backend and render the page of data how
I can use one server that is node `server.js` and it displays page of react and use webpack for bundle code without using webpack dev server?

Answer (score 1):

After installing webpack globally.

`npm install webpack -g`

you can easily bundle a file.

`webpack ./entry_file.js output_file.js`

so that u can use output_file.js in your webpage.

Comment: what do u mean outputfile?

Comment: output_file.js is a file which we get compressed file. So that u can use output_file.js in page.

Comment: have u installed webpack ?

Comment: ya i install but u see up there is files but down he said like this http://imgur.com/xIOHBdC

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to run a `dev server`, comment this part in the `webpack.config.js`:

```
   // devServer: {
   //    inline: true,
   //    port: 8080
   // },
```

After that run this command to resolve the error u r getting: **`sudo ln -s /usr/bin/nodejs /usr/bin/node`**

And then directly run `webpack -w --progress` for development mode and `webpack -p --progress` for prod inside `frontend directry`, it will create the bundle for you.

Comment: this is my webpack config js
module.exports = {
  entry: [
    './views/index.jsx'
  ],
  output: {
    path: __dirname,
    publicPath: '/',
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [{
      exclude: /node_modules/,
      loader: 'babel',
      query: {
        presets: ['react', 'es2015', 'stage-1']
      }
    }]
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx']
  },
  devServer: {
    historyApiFallback: true,
    contentBase: './'
  }
};

Comment: this one is correct, u can use the command i mentioned, r u getting any error when u run it ??

Comment: just now i saw the error, u need to run this command to resolve that, `sudo ln -s /usr/bin/nodejs /usr/bin/node` then run the `webpack -w --progress` command. it will work.

Comment: i try this webpack -w --progress and i got 
Hash: e749cb743281ac98acf1  
Version: webpack 1.14.0
Time: 1737ms
    Asset    Size  Chunks             Chunk Names
bundle.js  780 kB       0  [emitted]  main
   [0] multi main 28 bytes {0} [built]
    + 214 hidden modules


but how page of html open when run node server.js ??@Mayank Shukla

Comment: ur original issue got resolved :), now ur bundle.js file has been created. What u need to do is whenever any request is coming to ur server for base url, read and return this html file, rest everything it will handle, google it how to return file by language u r using for server.

Comment: u mean how to return html file by node js

Comment: i did this res.render('./index.html',{data:mainObj}, function(err, html) {
          if(err){
           console.error("Error Rendering ::", err)
           res.status(503).send("503 Service Unavailable" )
          }else{

           res.send(html);
          }
   });

Comment: and i receive this error 
{ [Error: Cannot find module 'html'] code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND' }
{ [Error: Cannot find module 'html'] code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND' }
_http_outgoing.js:335
    throw new Error('Can\'t set headers after they are sent.');
    ^

Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.
    at ServerResponse.OutgoingMessage.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:335:11)
 Mayank Shukla

Comment: sorry :) dont have much idea about node.js, try this i think it will work: `fs.readFile('frontend/public/index.html' , function(err, contents) {
      res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
          res.end(contents);
        });` ask about this to someone whole knows about node.js